# Click on a span causes blur event which moves the span so that it doesn't register click

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a span to the right of an input, both with some text in them. The input has whatever default width the browser chooses. The input has a blur handler to turn it into a new span with the same text as was in the blurred input. The span has the reverse operation: a click handler to turn it into a new input with the same text as was in the clicked span.

When the span to the right of the input is clicked, the input registers it's blur event and becomes a span, as designed. However it also becomes smaller (assuming not a lot of text) which is also desired. This makes the span that was clicked move over to the left.

The problem: The original span that we clicked now may not be under the mouse pointer and no longer registers the click.

The HTML:

```
<input id="write" class="tag" value="stuff"></input>
<span id="read" class="tag">some text</span>
```

The js:

```
var write = document.getElementById("write");
var read = document.getElementById("read");

var writeOnBlur = function() {
    var newRead = document.createElement("span");
        newRead.className = "tag";
        newRead.innerHTML = this.value;
        newRead.onclick = readOnClick;
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(newRead, this);
        newRead.focus();
}

var readOnClick = function(e) {
    alert("clicked the 'read' node");

    var newWrite = document.createElement("input");
    newWrite.className = "tag";
    newWrite.value = this.innerHTML;
    newWrite.onblur = writeOnBlur;
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(newWrite, this);
    newWrite.focus();
    e.stopPropagation();
}

document.onclick = function() {
    alert("missed the read node. clicked the document.");
}

read.onclick = readOnClick;
write.onblur = writeOnBlur;
write.focus();
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7s7kbvvf/10/

Click the span that contains "some text" to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a decent solution by allowing the parent node (or for simplicity in my example here, the document) handle the events. The document tracks the current "write tag" (input) so that when a "read tag" (span) is clicked, it can first replace the span with a new input and then the current input with a new span, both in one click. Since the span is replaced with a new input first, it doesn't matter that it moves once the existing input turns into a new span.

The new js (or see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/21cggnm7/1/)):

```
var write = document.getElementById("write");
var read = document.getElementById("read");
var currWrite = write;
write.focus();

document.onclick = function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (target && target.nodeName === "SPAN") {
        var newWrite = document.createElement("input");
        newWrite.className = "tag";
        newWrite.value = target.innerHTML;
        target.parentNode.replaceChild(newWrite, target);
    }
    if (currWrite !== null) {
        var newRead = document.createElement("span");
        newRead.className = "tag";
        newRead.innerHTML = currWrite.value;
        currWrite.parentNode.replaceChild(newRead, currWrite);
        currWrite = null;
    }
    if (newWrite) {
        currWrite = newWrite;
        newWrite.focus();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated to Javascript based solution for what you want:

```
   var switchToInput = function () {
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.className = "tag";
      input.type = "text";
      input.innerHTML = this.value;
      this.parentNode.replaceChild(input, this);
      input.onblur = switchToSpan;
      input.select();
  };
  var switchToSpan = function () {
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      span.className = "tag";
      span.innerHTML = this.value;
      this.parentNode.replaceChild(span, this);
      span.onclick = switchToInput;
  }
  var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('tag');
  for (var i = 0, limit = tags.length; i < limit; i++) {
      tags[i].onclick = switchToInput;
  }
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7s7kbvvf/9/

Comment: While this works, I am curious if it can be down without setting the width of the tags. I want the spans to be the size of their text, not much greater. If anything, I'd prefer the input to change size as you typed in it, which could probably be done with a little more heavy lifting around key events. Also I was hoping for a non-jQuery solution.

Comment: I am not sure what your logic was here. If you think I am missing the "switchToInput" logic in my original code, I omitted that to just highlight the root issue, which is that when the span is clicked and the input switches to a new span (due to blurring), the old span moves and doesn't register the click. There are also some minor issues in your code and the fiddle doesn't really work.

Comment: Not able to understand what you want? Confusseddddd :(

Comment: I have updated the code in my original question to include the logic to switch the span to an input. That wasn't the issue. Go to my fiddle and click on the "some text" span. Notice how the alert message is "missed the read node. clicked the document." The click causes the input to blur, turning it into a span, making it smaller, which moves the original /clicked/ span over to the left, away from where the mouse pointer is. Because it has moved, the click event on the original span doesn't register. I want it to register that click without having to keep the new "stuff" span fixed width.

Comment: It would register the event as the click has been already performed. Your alerts are confusing too...remove the alerts and try clicking on span/inputs...it seems to work fine.

Comment: It doesn't work fine. When you load the fiddle the left tag is an input and the right is a span. I want to click the right span, have the left input turn into a span and the right span turn into an input, all in one click. The alerts highlight the fact that the click event on the right span doesn't register on the span, only on the underlying document element.

Comment: That is happening because initally the focus is not set on the left texbox...hence the blur will not be called.

Comment: Not sure if you are talking about the fiddle in your answer or the one in my question. In my fiddle the left input definitely has focus. The one in yours doesn't have focus because you haven't called for it in your script. Even if you have the problem is still there. The only solution I have come up with so far is to have the parent element handle the events. See my answer.